# Decode substitute in Pyspark

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to convert a SQL DECODE function logic in Pyspark dataframe. What is best way to implement that?

```
decode(true,
is_date(DATE,'mm/dd/yy'),to_date(DATE,'mm/dd/yy'),
is_date(DATE,'month dd,yyyy'),to_date(DATE,'month dd,yyyy'),
is_date(DATE,'dd month,yyyy'),to_date(DATE,'dd month,yyyy'),
is_date(DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy'),to_date(DATE,'mm/dd/yyyy') ,null)
```

Any suggestion please.

Answer (score 0):

Use `case`.  Your `decode()` starts with `true`, which doesn't seem correct.  So, I think you want:

```
(case when is_date(DATE, 'mm/dd/yy') then to_date(DATE,'mm/dd/yy')
      when is_date(DATE, 'month dd,yyyy') then to_date(DATE,'month dd,yyyy')
      when is_date(DATE, 'dd month,yyyy') then to_date(DATE, 'dd month,yyyy'),
      when is_date(DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy') then to_date(DATE, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
 end)
```

I don't know if your environment supports `is_date()` or `to_date()` with a format argument (these are not standard SparkSQL functions), but your question is about `decode()`.

If your question is really about these functions, then ask a *new* question and be very clear out the question, along with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

the below code might help you:

```
df.withColumn('col1_modified', when(df.col1.isNull(), 'user_defined_1').when(df.col1==<col1_value>, 'user_defined_2').otherwise(df.col1)).show()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You should read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Please make sure to use code tags when posting code.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import decode

df = spark.createDataFrame([('A',), ('B',), ('C',), ('D',), ('F',)], ['grade'])

df = df.withColumn('score', decode(df.grade, {'A': 4, 'B': 3, 'C': 2, 'D': 1, 'F': 0}))
```

In the code above, we first create a DataFrame with the grade column containing the letter grades. We then use the decode function to create a new column score by mapping the values in the grade column to their corresponding numeric scores. The first argument to decode is the column we want to map (`df.grade`), and the second argument is a dictionary that maps each letter grade to its corresponding score.

After running this code, the df DataFrame should have a new column named score with the following values: 4, 3, 2, 1, and 0.