# Pyspark read.text with Encoding

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to read a file with ANSI encoding. It is a fixed size file (not CSV).

When I use the code below to place the file in a Pyspark dataframe I had a problem with the encode.

```
def Cria_df(d_spark, d_minio_client, d_bucket, d_arquivo, d_schema):
    #ISO-8859-1 / windows-1252
    #https://medium.com/@diangermishuizen/convert-the-character-set-encoding-of-a-string-field-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-on-databricks-3c841531e5a8
    df = d_spark.read.text("s3a://"+d_bucket+"/"+d_arquivo)
    df.show()
    #df = d_spark.read.option('encoding', 'windows-1252').text("s3a://"+d_bucket+"/"+d_arquivo, encoding="latin1")
    for colinfo in d_schema:
        df = df.withColumn(colinfo[0],df.value.substr(colinfo[1],colinfo[2]))
    
    header=df.first()[0]
    df = df.filter(~col("value").contains(header))
    df = df.drop('value')

    return df
```

Image of the problem dataframe:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZsWY.png)

How can I get this encoding right?

Did not work
[text](https://medium.com/@diangermishuizen/convert-the-character-set-encoding-of-a-string-field-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-on-databricks-3c841531e5a8)

Work:
[Decode substitute in Pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423574/decode-substitute-in-pyspark)

```
def Cria_df(d_spark, d_minio_client, d_bucket, d_arquivo, d_schema):
#ISO-8859-1 / windows-1252
#https://medium.com/@diangermishuizen/convert-the-character-set-encoding-of-a-string-field-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-on-databricks-3c841531e5a8
#https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57423574/decode-substitute-in-pyspark
df = d_spark.read.text("s3a://"+d_bucket+"/"+d_arquivo)
df = df.withColumn('value', decode(df.value, "windows-1252"))

#df = d_spark.read.option('encoding', 'windows-1252').text("s3a://"+d_bucket+"/"+d_arquivo, encoding="latin1")
for colinfo in d_schema:
    df = df.withColumn(colinfo[0],df.value.substr(colinfo[1],colinfo[2]))

header=df.first()[0]
df = df.filter(~col("value").contains(header))
df = df.drop('value')
#df.show()
return df
```

Comment: are you using Azure databricks?

Comment: No. Local Python and Minio

Comment: If the text is encoded, then you need to use the `pypsark.sql.functions.decode` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.decode.html). Have you tried reading the file using `spark.read.text` and applying the `decode` transformation?

Comment: ARCrpw, I'm new with python, little experience. I don't know how to use what you suggested. Can you help me?

Comment: My code:

import os
import pandas as pd
from minio import Minio
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr
#from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from minio import Minio

Comment: def Cria_df(d_spark, d_minio_client, d_bucket, d_arquivo, d_schema):
    #ISO-8859-1 / windows-1252
    #https://medium.com/@diangermishuizen/convert-the-character-set-encoding-of-a-string-field-in-a-pyspark-dataframe-on-databricks-3c841531e5a8
    df = d_spark.read.text("s3a://"+d_bucket+"/"+d_arquivo)
    df.select(expr.decode("value", "UTF-8")).show() #<<dont working